# The Achilles Twins Paradox: Proof of a Preferred Frame?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, time-dilation

The Achilles Twins Paradox: Proof of a Preferred Frame?

Abstract: Both Achilles and Bob spend the exact same amount of time accelerating and decelerating at the same rates. Both Achilles and Bob spend the exact same amount of time in inertial frames moving at the exact same constant velocities relative to one-another.  The only asymmetry is that they spend different amounts of times in different inertial frames.  Hence the cause of their difference in age is due to the difference of inertial frames, and hence there is a preferred frame.

The Achilles Twins Paradox: Proof of a Preferred Frame

Consider two twins Achilles and Bob standing together on a spaceship. Achilles and Bob both accelerate to .99c in one minute as they travel side-by-side away from their spaceship. After one year of traveling at .99c together, Achilles spends a minute decelerating to rejoin the rest frame of the spaceship, while Bob continues to travel away from the spaceship at .99c. Achilles then accelerates to .99c in one minute in the direction of the spaceship, and when he returns to the spaceship, he spends a minute decelerating to rejoin the rest frame of the spaceship.

Meanwhile, Bob continues to spend the next ten years traveling at .99c away from the spaceship. After ten years have passed, Bob spends a minute decelerating to rejoin the rest frame of the spaceship. Bob then accelerates to .99c in one minute in the direction of the spaceship, and when he returns to the spaceship, he spends a minute decelerating to rejoin the rest frame of the spaceship, where he is reunited with Achilles.

Both Achilles and Bob spent the exact same amount of time accelerating and decelerating at the same rates. Both Achilles and Bob spent the exact same amount of time in inertial frames moving at the exact same constant velocities relative to one-another.

Who will be younger?

And more importantly, who will be younger and why?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145661/discussion-on-question-by-epic-mythology-the-achilles-twins-paradox-proof-of-a); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Bob will be younger. The effect at the heart of the twin paradox is the shift in reference frame at the turnaround point, and the magnitude of that effect increases with distance. Given that Bob's turnaround point is much further away than Achilles', the effect will be greater in Bob's case.

This has no implications whatsoever for a preferred frame. You could repeat the experiment in many different frames and the same rules would apply regardless.

Comment: The effect at the _heart_ of the TP is "differential aging", not turnaround and acceleration.  If you insist on answering in that way, you should provide a full calculation for us _in terms of turnaround and acceleration_ that we can all check.  I suspect it will be considerably more complicated that the two lines of algebra that are _really_ at the heart of the effect!

Comment: @m4r35n357 The differential aging is the same for all observers. It's simply the time reported by the travelers after their reunion. Why is this so? Because it's a scalar, just like the number of beans in a jar. Coordinate system transformations do not change such a count. It's not even necessary to know what the exact number is. We automatically know that it has to be the same, otherwise the theory would be completely wrong, which it isn't.

Comment: @m4r35n357 The differential ageing is the supposed paradox. The shift of reference frame at the turnaround accounts for it. If you read any of then tens of answers I have posted on PSE you will see that I never include calculations, so I am not about to break my golden rule now!